# Hot to get an Azure AD Id_token over an Azure Mobile App?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-mobile-services, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-authentication

I'm trying to get an Id_token over Azure Mobile App but I'm receiving an mobileServiceAuthenticationToken.

The mobileServiceAuthenticationToken is received by my iOS-App with the following implementation: [Integrate Azure AD into an iOS app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-ios)

I need the Id_token (with algorithm RS256) because my backend-service (java spring-boot) needs to validate this token, which is not possible with the mobileServiceAuthenticationToken. mobileServiceAuthenticationToken is based on algorithm HS256 (which needs a client secret) and does not allow requesting the Azure AD for getting user informations over the Microsoft Graph Api.

Here is a link to microsoft reference for further informations: [Azure AD token reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims)

Answer (score 0):

The `id_token` is not able to call the Microsoft Graph REST. To call Microsoft Graph REST, we need to acquire the corresponding `access_token` for it which's `aud` claim is `https://graph.microsoft.com`.

There are two kinds of flows for mobile authentication, client-flow and server-flow. Both of them should work in your scenario, however the progress is a little different.

**Client flow**:
For this flow, you can get the `id_token` and `access_token` for Microsoft Graph from Azure Active Directory first using [ADAL SDK](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc). Then you can exchange the id_token with EasyAuth for the authentication token and login your mobile app.

**Server flow**:You can config the mobile app to acquire the **access_token** for Microsoft Graph. Then you can implement an proxy in the mobile back-end. After that you can only need to call the mobile back-end both your owner service and Microsoft Graph.

Here are some helpful articles about this topic:

[How to: Authenticate users with the Active Directory Authentication Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-how-to-use-client-library#adal)

[App Service Auth and the Azure AD Graph API](https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/25/app-service-auth-aad-graph-api/)

Comment: Hi Fei Xue! Thanks for your answer. I think I haven't explained my targeted solutions well enough. I'd like to get an token from the Azure AD and verify on my own java backend that the token is valid. My iOS App should get the Azure AD token and send it to my own java backend service which is not on Azure. Do you have an idea how I can solve this?